# What is the simplest configuration to set up HMR Create-React-app to run behind nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Im trying a consistently failing to run the default CRA with hot module reload behind a reverse proxy. The app works fine but the HMR is not working and there is a console error: "webpackHotDevClient.js:60 WebSocket connection to 'wss://react.syntapse.co.uk/sockjs-node' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name react.syntapse.co.uk;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3120/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
    location /sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3120/sockjs-node/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
     }
}
```

.env configuration:

```
PORT=3120
```

console error:

```
webpackHotDevClient.js:60 WebSocket connection to 'wss://react.syntapse.co.uk/sockjs-node' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js @ webpackHotDevClient.js:60
webpackHotDevClient.js:76 The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
```

the wss://react.syntapse.co.uk/sockjs-node looks perfectly valid so not sure why its failing.

any help or advice appreciated. thanks.

Comment: the WSS protocol uses port 443 by default, you might want to use `ws` instead of `wss`

Comment: your config says port 80 which needs `ws` ... are you terminating tls inside nginx or do you wish to send https traffic to your downstream server ... if you wish to terminate tls using your nginx ( https -> http ) then you want `listen 443 ssl;`  along with necessary tls key and cert files ... often downstream server code leaves off mention of `wss://xxx` or `ws://xxx` and instead uses `://xxx` to auto pickup either

Comment: thanks Scott and Smakusors. my setup is a docker proxy (https) -> app proxy (http) -> app(s). So the docker-proxy provides the encryption and the app proxy is http. standard setup for dockerised apps i think. Docker proxy converts https to http and app proxy and apps are unsecured. Is there a way to make same work for ws in this kind of setup? thanks.